# is there mathematical model to describe the relationship between running time and input data size for hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

in hadoop cluster, is there mathematical model to describe the curve about the transmission time and datainputSize of Mapper?

For example, if the original data size is N for M Mappers, and the total transmission time from  all the Mappers to Reducers is T. Now I wanna double the data size to 2N in Mappers, is there approximation estimation for the transmission time T'(I think T'  must be less than 2T), So my idea is to use log curve to describe this curve, but I am not sure it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your input is coming from the HDFS(?)
I also assume that your input data has already been placed on the HDFS, so we're not talking about the time to transmit your input data from your local file store to the HDFS.
I assume then that your input size N is the total size of all of your input files combined.
I assume M is the number of map tasks (based on the number of input splits that your input files are broken into).
If we're talking about transmission between the map tasks and the reduce tasks then we need to know the size of the output from your map operations. In general, the size of this output is unrelated to the size of the input N.

Even if we knew how much total data needs to be transmitted between the map tasks and the reduce tasks, asking for the transmission time is not necessarily meaningful, because this transmission can happen at the same time as your map and reduce tasks are executing, and it will be a series of individual transmissions between individual map tasks and reduce tasks that each happen at different points in time. The goal of a well written hadoop application is to hide this transmission time by overlapping computation and communication.